# DMS Source connection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-dms

> Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=1022506,
>   errMessage=Failed to connect Network error has occurred, errDetails=
>   RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HYT00 NativeError: 0 Message:
>   [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout
>   expired ODBC general error.

I am getting this while creating DMS source. I have created a firewall inbound rules also. Target successfully tested.
My goal is migrate on premises SQL server db to aws sql instance, which is installed in aws-EC2.

Anyone please help me.

Thanks in Advance.